# Need a little help for this scheme "leet-speak"

Tags: recursion, dictionary, scheme

I wrote a program below for "Define a procedure leet-speak takes a string and returns the result of changing all s's to fives, all e's to threes, all l's to ones, and all o's to zeros. Do not write any recursive code to do this. Simply make use of `string->list`, `map`, and `list->string`."

The error I got is:

```
 ~ (leet-speak "leet speak neat speak")
 Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure (1 3 3 #\t #\space 5 ...)
```

Here is my definition for `leet-speak`:

```
(define leet-speak
  (lambda (y)
    (list->string 
      ((map 
         (lambda (x)
           (cond
             [(eq? #\l x) 1]
             [(eq? #\s x) 5]
             [(eq? #\o x) 0]
             [(eq? #\e x) 3]
             [else x])
           ) (string->list y )))))
```

I really can't find out where the problem is.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I've just been looking at the diffs and I'm really confused.  I did not add the "Hi" and the code definitely did not look formatted before I added the spaces.  It was all one line when I first looked at it.  I appreciate the evidence says otherwise, but the code formatting was not originally there (it was just missing spaces at the start of each line).  I'm not quite sure what has happened, but appologies for not improving a post.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for explaining. It sounds like the OP edited the post after you started making your edits. Stack Overflow coalesces all edits within a 5-minute window, so further edits that the OP made within that window won't show up in the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many parentheses around the `map`. Remove the extra so that there's only one parenthesis before `map`, and you should be good to go.

Your `cond` also needs to return the *character* corresponding to the number, not the number itself. Also, consider using a `case` instead of the `cond` you have.

All up, here's how it would look:

```
(define (leet-speak str)
  (list->string 
   (map (lambda (x)
          (case x
            [(#\l) #\1]
            [(#\s) #\5]
            [(#\o) #\0]
            [(#\e) #\3]
            [else x]))
        (string->list str))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I know what does the "case" use for?

Comment: `case` in Scheme is analogous to `switch` in C-style languages.